# how to insert '-' in money column when value is 0.00

Tags: sql-server

How to insert `'-'` when value is `0.00` in result set, the summary in crystal report doesn't work?

```
Create Table #Results
(
    TerminalNumber       INT,
    ContractNumber       VARCHAR(50),
    CustomerName  VARCHAR(80),
    TotalDeficiency NUMERIC(13,2),
    TotalIncremental NUMERIC(13,2),
    MonthPeriod VARCHAR(20)
)




SELECT TerminalNumber
      ,ContractNumber
      ,CustomerName
      ,CASE WHEN TotalDeficiency = 0.00 THEN '-' ELSE CAST(TotalDeficiency AS NUMERIC(13,2)) END AS TotalDeficiency 
      ,CASE WHEN TotalIncremental = 0.00 THEN '-' ELSE CAST(TotalIncremental AS NUMERIC(13,2)) END AS TotalIncremental 
      ,MonthPeriod
      ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @billing_date, 101) 'BillingDate' 
      FROM #Results order by CustomerName
```

Comment: Noway. Why do you want that?

Comment: You can't, `MONEY` is a numeric data type, not a string.

Comment: how can I achieve this then...do i need to change to decimal datatype

Comment: This kind of formatting should be best left to the client side, not the SQL side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `CASE` if you need it in presentation.

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
    WHEN TotalDeficiency = 0.00 THEN '-' 
    ELSE CAST(TotalDeficiency AS VARCHAR(10))
   END AS TotalDeficiency
FROM #Results;
```

or `IIF` if using `SQL Server 2012+`

```
SELECT
  IIF(TotalDeficiency = 0.00, '-', CAST(TotalDeficiency AS VARCHAR(10)) ) 
  AS TotalDeficiency 
FROM #Results;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382277)**</kbd>

You cannot insert character `-` in `MONEY` column though.

Comment: `ELSE CAST(TotalDeficiency AS VARCHAR(10))` or something like that

Comment: I will point out that is may perform faster to do this in the application code than here. You should test both ways.

Comment: I am trying to use numeric datatype and try to perform summary in crystal report but summary doesn't work when i use '-' in query

Comment: see modified question

Comment: @user1030181 `-` is character. For sum/avg you need NUMERIC datatype. The best way is in my opinion to get data as MONEY, do necessary calculation and in the end before presenting it to user change 0.00 to `-` in aplication